# Get permission denied message when creating a file to /var/log on os x

Tags: macos, qt, file, privileges, permission-denied

I want to write qt application log to /var/log/message_app.log on OS X. I am getting

> "Cannot open file for writing:  "Permission denied""

message on console.

This is the my test code parts:

```
logfile = fopen(logFilePath, "a");
  if (!logfile) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to access keystroke log file. Please make sure you have the correct permissions.\n");
  }
```

and

```
      QString filename = "/var/log/data.txt";
      QFile file(filename);
      file.setPermissions(QFile::ExeGroup);
      file.setPermissions(QFile::ExeOther);
      file.setPermissions(QFile::ExeOwner);
      file.setPermissions(QFile::ExeUser);
      if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
          qDebug() << "Cannot open file for writing: " << file.errorString();
          return 0;
      }
      else {
          QTextStream stream(&file);
          stream << "something" << endl;
      }
```

Both of them return same error.

When I start QtCreator from console using sudo command, it works. But when I deployed my app and change some permissions (with chown, chmod, etc.) it doesn't work.

I googled and found out some privileged issues like [that](https://github.com/mbsanchez/QtPrivilegedHelperExample).

So, is there any other effective solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, obviously only root user has the permissions to write to that folder (and thats by design). Either the system admin has to make the directory writable for all users, or you must log to user-specific directory (e.g. `$HOME/.log`). The second one is preferred

Comment: Actually I try to obtain keystrokes (like a keylogger). I tried to save user space but keylogger does not work. I am using [this](https://github.com/GiacomoLaw/Keylogger) source. This only obtains keystrokes when program run on terminal with sudo. But I need to run it without terminal.